# How to edit header of one page of book class?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use the `book` document class and make the headers with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, reqno, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead{gggggggggggggggggggg }

\rhead{\parbox{0.58\linewidth}{\begin{center}\small{\leftmark}\end{center}}}

\rfoot{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\makeatletter

\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to change right header on one page, can you help me ??

I tried to use : `\thispagestyle{empty}` to delete the header on one page.

Comment: You can create a new page style and then you call it using `\thispagestyle{}`.

Comment: What page do you want with a different style? The one with the chapter title?

Answer (score 1):

I'll do with the assumption that you don't want the header in the chapter starting page:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, reqno,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{gggggggggggggggggggg}
\fancyhead[R]{\makebox[0.58\linewidth]{\small\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}%
}


\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % as recommended by fancyhdr

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

There's no need for a `\parbox`, unless your titles are unusually long. However I'd set them flush right. If you really need a `\parbox`, don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in it, but

```
\parbox{<length>}{\centering <contents>}
```

and don't forget to look at the warnings by `fancyhdr` to know the correct value to assign to `\headheight`.

If you need to change the page style for other pages, define a specific style:

```
\fancypagestyle{peculiar}{% use whatever name you please
  \fancyhf{}% clear all the headers and footers
  % now define the contents of the various fields
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  %...
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% rule at the top
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}% rule at the bottom
}
```

and issue `\thispagestyle{peculiar}` where you need it. By redefining the `plain` page style you have a different style on the chapter starting pages.